# How to import a JSON file to Cloud Firestore

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had developed a web app on a mySQL database and now I am switching to Android Mobile Development but I have large amount of data to be exported into Firebase's Cloud Firestore. I could not find a way to do so, I have the mySQL data stored in JSON and CSV.

Do I have to write a script? If yes then can you share the script or is there some sort of tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have large amounts of data to be exported into Firebase's Cloud Firestore, I could not find a way to do so

If you're looking for a "magic" button that can convert your data from a MySQL database to a Cloud Firestore database, please note that there isn't one.

> Do I have to write a script?

Yes, you have to write code in order to convert your actual MySQL database into a Cloud Firestore database. Please note that both types of databases share two different concepts. For instance, a Cloud Firestore database is composed of collections and documents. There are no tables in the NoSQL world.

So, I suggest you read the official documentation regarding [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

> If yes then can you share the script or is there some sort of tool.

There is no script and no tool for that. You should create your own mechanism for that.

Comment: Can you help me out with such script? Or will I have to do the entire thing manually?

Comment: Yes, you are guessing right. You should do the entire coding manually. Give it a try and if you have a hard time implementing it, post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey, I have no idea, where to begin with writing a script like that, can you help me out?

Comment: You should try to get it started with official documentation, as I showed you in my answer. You'll find everything you need there.